# GridMvc.Html on click- Paging or Sorting to hit HTTPPOST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, grid.mvc

I have a GridMvc.Html in my web app.

**My Requirement**
On Click of the Paging\Sorting functionality  I want it to hit HTTPPOST Action Method.

Currently it hits only HTTPGET.

**I have tried**
 using jQuery, it doesn't work and I am not sure on it too.

**EDIT**
This is my Grid in the View

```
@Html.Grid(Model.SignalDataList).Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Add(s => s.SignalName).Titled("Name");
    columns.Add(s => s.TimeReceived).Titled("Time Received").Filterable(true);
    columns.Add(s => s.Value).Titled("Value").Filterable(true);

}).WithPaging(10).Sortable(true)
```

c

Each click on page goes to HTTPGet. SO the data I have selected\filtered via DropDown cannot be handled.

```
public ActionResult AlarmSignalData()
    {
        SignalDataRepository signalDb = new SignalDataRepository();
        ...
        try
        {
           GetData();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) { return View("Error", new HandleErrorInfo(ex, "SignalData", "AlarmSignalData")); }
        return View(signalDataView);
    }
```

But I want it to hit HTTPPOST , coz I want to process selected data in trextbox\DropDownlist in my View
So in HTTPPOST I pass my model, from Where I can take the TextBox\DropdownList values to fetch filtered data

```
[HTTPPOST]public ActionResult AlarmSignalData(Model model)
    {
        SignalDataRepository signalDb = new SignalDataRepository();
        ...
        try
        {
           GetData(model.SelectSignal,model.FromDate,model,ToData);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) { return View("Error", new HandleErrorInfo(ex, "SignalData", "AlarmSignalData")); }
        return View(signalDataView);
    }
```

Comment: do you have any code to add or shall we just make some up?

Comment: if you registered the parameters in the method with the same name of get request the values will deliver to the server if that what you searching for ?!

Comment: On click of the paging\sorting of _Grid.MVC_ I want it to hit the _HTTPPOST_ method , so that I will be able to fetch the filtered data calling the method `GetData(signalName,FromDate,ToDate)` (which is inside the _HTTPPOST_ method) -
 with the model data  . Currently paging\sorting click hits the _HTTPGET_  where I don't have model variables to handle & fetch the filter data.

Comment: Any idea on how to get the Grid's clicks to HttpPost method? I appreciate any help on this. Thanks in advance.